# Dataframe group by index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing, group-by

Sample dataframe:

```
              A
date          
2010-01-01    1
2010-01-02    2
2010-02-01    3
2010-02-02    4
2010-03-01    5
2010-03-02    6
```

I want to return another dataframe grouped by month, so I have done:

```
month = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).first()

# outcome

           A
date          
2010-01    1
2010-02    3
2010-03    5
```

As you can see, I achieve my intent but I get only the first values of each month. My desired outcome should be.

```
           A
date          
2010-01    1
2010-01    2    
2010-02    3
2010-02    4
2010-03    5
2010-03    6
```

If I do:

```
month = df.groupby(df.index.to_period('M'))

# without **.first()**
```

I get nothing.

Any suggestion on how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.to_period`:

First, ensure that your index is DateTimeIndex:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.to_period('M')
```

Output:

```
         A
date      
2010-01  1
2010-01  2
2010-02  3
2010-02  4
2010-03  5
2010-03  6
```

​

Comment: Great, you made my day :). I have a last question: if I want to do a **for loop** by selecting the first two months and returning a df, then selecting next two months (dropping the first month) and returning another df, until the end of data... is it feasible? any suggestion on how to achieve it? thansk!

Comment: Actually, @LouiseLop this is a separate question and should be submitted as a new question.  I suggest you create new question with your "for loop" request.

Comment: Thank you, I have formulated this question as a separate one here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173509/dataframe-rolling-using-index-datetime

Comment: @LouiseLop Sorry.  I was on vacation a few days there.   I took a stab at your question on the above post.